# AngularJs $q.all no data

Tags: angularjs

I really need your help with the following.
I inquire Firebase, get a list of tasks by priority (task date), then cycle the results.
For each task is read it's related job (another branch in Firebase), put the result on a task property (jobObject) then return a promise.

In the end, $q.all should return all results. But it just doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong here?
http://jsfiddle.net/danielchindea/R4M7x/1/

```
        var startAt = '2014-03-01',
            endAt = '2014-03-31',
            promises = [];


        var getTask = function (task) {
            var d = $q.defer();

            jobRef.child(task.jobId).on('value', function (jobSnapshoot) {
                task.jobObject = jobSnapshoot.val();
                        d.resolve(task);
            });

            return d.promise;
        };


        taskRef.startAt(startAt).endAt(endAt).on('value', function (tasksSnapshoot) {
            angular.forEach(_.values(tasksSnapshoot.val()), (function (task) {
                if (task) {
                  promises.push(getTask(task));
                }
            }));
            console.log('finish');
        });

        // it was $q.all($scope.promises) but this isn't the issue

        $q.all(promises).then(function (result) {
            $scope.events = result;
            console.log('results' + result);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that this block is async:

```
taskRef.startAt(startAt).endAt(endAt).on('value', function (tasksSnapshoot) {
```

and When the further code gets executed, `promises` is still an empty array:

```
$q.all(promises).then(function (result) {
```

since `promises` is just an empty array (without unresolved promises) `$q.all` gets triggered immediately after the end of run stack (*with an empty array as a result*).

#### Solution - http://jsfiddle.net/R4M7x/7/

```
taskRef.startAt(startAt).endAt(endAt).on('value', function (tasksSnapshoot) {
    angular.forEach(_.values(tasksSnapshoot.val()), (function (task) {
        if (task) {
          promises.push(getTask(task));
        }
    }));

    $q.all(promises).then(function (result) {
        $scope.events = result;
        console.log('results' + result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Excelent answer. Saved my day. Would it be so much bother if you could help me turning this controller code into a service?

I mean how to return $q.all to controller, something like:

    $scope.events = XXXService.getTasks(year, month)
                .then(function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                });

Right now everything is running good from the controller. I understand my mistake. But from service is another thing. Please help.

Comment: Nevermind, I did it. Thank you Ilan and Leon for your kind help.

I declared another deferred=$q.defer() at the begining of the service.
Than, just outside of forEach but inside of call to firebase I put deferred.resolve(promises) i.e. I put all promises array created inside the cycle in another promise.

At the end of service:

` return $q.all([deferred.promise]).then(function () {
                    return $q.all(promises);
                });
`
Inside controller:
` XXXservice.getTasks(param)
                .then(function (res) {
                     $scope.events =res;
                });

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your running $q.all on $scope.promises and not promises

Comment: I corrected the thing. It was my mistake taking the code from my project to this post. It's not working anyways, so the problem remains. Thanks Leon.